# Syntax of a functional method call as an FM parameter?

Tags: abap, function-module

I have the following piece of code.

```
REPORT ZZY.

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      convert_to_xstring
        IMPORTING
          i_param1 TYPE i
          i_param2 TYPE i
        RETURNING
          VALUE(rv_result) TYPE xstring,
      main.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD convert_to_xstring.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD main.
    DATA: lt_binary_tab TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF x.

    DATA(lv_result) = convert_to_xstring( i_param1 = 1 i_param2 = 2 ).

    CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY'
      EXPORTING
        buffer = lcl_main=>convert_to_xstring(
                   EXPORTING
                     i_param1 = 1
                     i_param2 = 2
                 )
      TABLES
        binary_tab = lt_binary_tab.

  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lcl_main=>main( ).
```

A functional method call that is not a part of a function module call can be written like that.

```
DATA(lv_result) = convert_to_xstring( i_param1 = 1 i_param2 = 2 ).
```

However when I want to use it exactly as written above

```
CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY'
  EXPORTING
    buffer                = lcl_main=>convert_to_xstring( i_param1 = 1 i_param2 = 2 )
  TABLES
    binary_tab            = lt_binary_tab.
```

I get the following syntax error.

> Field "CONVERT_TO_XSTRING(" is unknown. It is neither in one of the
>   specified tables nor defined by a "DATA" statement. "DATA" statement.

It looks like the compiler needs some guidance in this case to distinguish between an attribute and a method. Why would it be ambiguous for the compiler to let such a case without writing `EXPORTING`?

```
CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY'
  EXPORTING
    buffer                = lcl_main=>convert_to_xstring( EXPORTING i_param1 = 1 i_param2 = 2 )
  TABLES
    binary_tab            = lt_binary_tab.
```

Comment: These method invocations are called [functional methods](https://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABAPMETHODS_FUNCTIONAL.htm), which is very different from an [inline function or method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function), which AFAIK doesn't exist in ABAP. I'd rather not confuse the two. And, as for your question - `CALL FUNCTION` is a mess - is that enough of an answer? ;-)

Comment: Isn't then speaking of an [inline](https://scn.sap.com/community/abap/blog/2013/05/23/abap-news-for-release-740--inline-declarations) declaration just as confusing? I will rephrase though, because this way of method call has been indeed named functional from the very beginning. I remember `inline` function in C++, they are good alternative for preprocessor macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The design of abap is quite bad. There is something like functional method calls, but you can't use it in combination with all commands. For example the `WRITE` command doesn't work in combination with functional method calls. This seems to be some kind of "partial compatible" with function method calls.
I don't know why(maybe the sap dev folks were drunk), but it is just a fact we have to live with.

Comment: Yep, I agree but in this case it is possible to use a functional method, only it has to be done with a "hack". I am wondering what would be the possible ambiguity here if the `EXPORTING` needn't have to be used.

Comment: I would guess, it's some kind of a "bug". But nobody knows, in the world of sap...